# Is there a chess.com Python api?

Tags: online-chess, python, chess.com

I want to program a bot and implement it on chess.com, but are there any types of chess.com Python api which will make the bot use the chess.com interface?

Comment: This seems a bit low effort. It's not difficult to do a web search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a Python wrapper to the Chess.com API. Here's the package: https://pypi.org/project/chess.com/

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to introduce my bot to the chess.com interface?. If there is a way can you please send a link of the documentation of it.